# iPhone - crash logs not generated on Windows

Tags: iphone, crash, crash-reports

I have some users testing my app on Windows and Mac platforms. The app crashes at some points but the Windows users cannot get any crash logs. Here's what they do

1. Run the app and play around till it crashes
2. Sync their device with iTunes
3. Look for logs here (on a Vista) C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\

But there is nothing inside the **Apple Computer** folder.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from you omitting parts of the path in that it should correctly be containing the login username - ow, now noticed you possibly did try to embed it, hence the double backspace after Users....

Ask your user if he possibly is using multiple computers for syncing his device. In case he does, he should check the machine he used first as those Logs are only synced with the "main"-machine, I believe. Bit of a shot in the dark but worth the attempt, I think.

Ow, and there may be another possible reason I just saw within [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744353/iphonehow-to-find-infrequent-device-crash) - credits to Kendall:
If there is not crash log, it could mean the app was shut down for using too much memory - in that case you should see a message come up in the device console indicating your application is being shut down.

Comment: AFAIK, crashes due to memory issues also generate crash logs (though I am not very sure). Will check any ways, thanks.