# iPhone:How to find infrequent device crash?

Tags: iphone

I am getting infrequent crashes from my source code project. I couldn't find out the exact reproducible steps though i have tried to reproduce so many times. During dubug on the device is becoming very hard to reproduce it, because it happens somewhere and sometimes. Is there any logs printing while crashing the device (or) any other tools/way to find out exactly where could it happen, in iPhone Xcode development?

Thanks and Appreciate your help on this.

Here is my app latest crash: Can someone find any reason?

Incident Identifier: 96E3C178-967C-4054-8470-A8628D77EDE1
CrashReporter Key:   0e061dbe05ca13005016137051a2c0ef819425e9
Process:         myapplication [4472]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/A8483A85-E5A5-46CF-B9B8-4D99F5C951F9/myapplication.app/myapplication
Identifier:      myapplication
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2009-11-17 17:27:49.366 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.0 (7A341)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.mycompany.myapplication failed to launch in time 
elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 3.630 (user 1.430, system 2.200), 18% CPU 
elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 1.050, 5% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d47158 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d49ed8 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3025454e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 982
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30254164 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 44
4   UIKit                           0x308f034c -[UIApplication _run] + 512
5   UIKit                           0x308eea8c UIApplicationMain + 960
6   myapplication                       0x00002090 main (main.m:14)
7   myapplication                       0x0000202c start + 44

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d47158 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d49ed8 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3025454e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 982
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30254164 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 44
4   WebCore                         0x3588dbc8 __ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 412
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d705a0 _pthread_body + 20

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0xbfff +myapplication armv6   /var/mobile/Applications/A8483A85-E5A5-46CF-B9B8-4D99F5C951F9/myapplication.app/myapplication
   0x1f000 -    0x22fff +MobileSubstrate.dylib armv6  /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib
   0x4d000 -    0x4efff  dns.so armv6  <7943354b648b9518f46a835d5359e45a> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
   0x51000 -    0x51fff +SimulatedKeyEvents.dylib arm  /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/SimulatedKeyEvents.dylib
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv6  <384bf84ebe2b822c3cb75fce3e8647d6> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30000000 - 0x30008fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x3000c000 - 0x3015bfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <92636cf8b8e8f3c10721667c48ca182b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x301ca000 - 0x301d8fff  libz.1.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x301fd000 - 0x302a8fff  CoreFoundation armv6  <3e02f5628a56bce4c9eb1c5e49c863d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x30501000 - 0x305f5fff  Foundation armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3071d000 - 0x30729fff  CoreVideo armv6  <5404da375ad190f3e1404e5e8a70f764> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3073a000 - 0x30760fff  AppSupport armv6  <1baa1e22eb94eb405d724a2f6b219f53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30778000 - 0x3077dfff  liblockdown.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x308ed000 - 0x31521fff  UIKit armv6  <73cf70d65e1afef2a6ae94fb81bf2fe4> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x31885000 - 0x318d1fff  IOKit armv6  <56ba629c062ac21a045914430412c5f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x318e9000 - 0x31aa2fff  CoreGraphics armv6  <80bccae4ab17a49f7fc3a66bb2def894> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31af1000 - 0x31b58fff  CFNetwork armv6  <863076d9b768c76272e3f0f686ca355d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31bb2000 - 0x31bc8fff  OpenGLES armv6  <2c30348868df45d3b8e0e398e0e4f727> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x31bcf000 - 0x31cccfff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <619918c7282aa5b53ac3ad32c320b7a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31d46000 - 0x31e69fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x31ea9000 - 0x31feffff  AudioToolbox armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x32041000 - 0x3204bfff  GraphicsServices armv6  <99b0baa68c257ca5d2fed21bd409ea20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3209b000 - 0x320cefff  Security armv6  <34c21a865d91e9a13477e9395c516f8c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x320e8000 - 0x32194fff  ImageIO armv6  <44921d26b2b796c2c707c87c68026b16> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x32369000 - 0x3239cfff  SystemConfiguration armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x324c6000 - 0x32521fff  CoreAudio armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x325b2000 - 0x325cefff  AddressBook armv6  <3023a336aec321324b5a310ee66687f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x3291c000 - 0x329c4fff  QuartzCore armv6  <1cf2a12e661e1a49f90553b013283b29> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x32a16000 - 0x32a16fff  CoreSurface armv6  <2c60135f696b1a787443c4a68e1aced2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x32a1b000 - 0x32a1cfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <05aa0565d0f6813003dc5dc175af6048> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32e0c000 - 0x32f0dfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <3f78cbbe6b5b7d3b4c5753627fcebdee> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3311e000 - 0x33213fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <3398aecf5ef07d7bbe6673fc9ab570fb> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x332c9000 - 0x33372fff  WebKit armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3415c000 - 0x34165fff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <4997adf422af4a9eecf25aa9bcaf8fc9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x347f5000 - 0x34812fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <7e34a4dd5c5b0400d10b01e998d5b2de> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x34c0e000 - 0x34c14fff  MBX2D armv6  <6815ceba8853af0095f160b6d3c88937> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x3553e000 - 0x3557bfff  CoreText armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x355c8000 - 0x355ccfff  IOSurface armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3580b000 - 0x35f5afff  WebCore armv6  <98f065e46e4c230bf091abaf6da60c16> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36422000 - 0x3647cfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <456f75f502443d281147f36f6ed4c3d3> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3648a000 - 0x36493fff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <2528ee7a4fd041090850f1845c393b84> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x36496000 - 0x364a6fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <44ee6b2c59cd5aa70d59f7d0d0d3b0b2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x37124000 - 0x3712efff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <9adf227705e932c47e703f73ca1d87c2> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3748a000 - 0x374f3fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <44d54be7409eedbf35157cc538ea660b> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x37c74000 - 0x37c74fff  Accelerate armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x37cc8000 - 0x37d0bfff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <5632d3e7799c5c90540157938bce4b95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x37d12000 - 0x37d12fff  vecLib armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to get a [crash log](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH7-SW37).

In the crash log, you'll have a [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) of what was happening when the application crashed.

Look through the stack trace for the last thing you were doing. The last thing in the trace will likely be within a framework method that you call, so trace the call back to your code and use that as the starting point.

Once you know where in your code the crash occurred, try to think of what might have caused the crash. If you're having trouble seeing what might have caused the crash, post the line that lead to the crash (along with the surround code) here and we might have some insight as to what caused it.

If you're also looking for resources on what Xcode has to offer to debug, have a read of the [Xcode Debugging Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/000-Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Hi Ben, one more question, i got like a crash but didn't find any logs there. Does it mean, was it not a crash (or) is there any chance in the device to not storing the logs for some reason?

Comment: If there is not crash log, it could mean the app was shut down for using too much memory - in that case you should see a message come up in the device console indicating your application is being shut down.

Answer (score 0):

Using static analysis on Xcode in 10.6 will probably be enlightening. I have found many errors that raised no warnings that way.